# Okhttp cache file not created(Not working okhttp caching)

Tags: android, caching, cache-control, okhttp

i want to say that i use the okhttp caching with Retrofit but cache file not created while i write the right code because i create a sample app where is working done but when i use same code in my project i am not understood why not create cache file.

Here is my code :

```
private Context context;
private PrefManager prefManager;

private String BEARER = "Bearer ";
private String APP_JSON = "application/json";
private String OUTPUT_ACCEPT = "Accept";
private String AUTHERIZATION = "Authorization";
private int CACHE_SIZE_BYTES = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
private String TAG = OkHttpClientModule.class.getSimpleName();


@Provides
public OkHttpClient okHttpClient(Cache cache, Interceptor interceptor, StethoInterceptor stethoInterceptor, HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    builder.cache(cache);

     builder.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     builder.writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     builder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        builder.addNetworkInterceptor(stethoInterceptor);
        builder.interceptors().add(httpLoggingInterceptor);
    }

    OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
    return client;
}

@Provides
public PrefManager getManager(Context context) {
    return new PrefManager(context);
}

@Provides
public StethoInterceptor getSteltho() {
    return new StethoInterceptor();
}


@Provides
public Cache cache(File cacheFile) {
    Cache cache = null;
    try {
        cache = new Cache(cacheFile, CACHE_SIZE_BYTES);
        Log.e("TAG", " cache created " + cache.directory().getPath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("TAG", " cache exception " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return cache;
}

@Provides
@RandomUserApplicationScope
public File file(@ApplicationContext Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    File file = new File(ctx.getCacheDir(), "httpcache");
    return file;
}


@Provides
public Interceptor getIntercepter() {
    final String mAuth = "";//Credentials.basic(BaseRequest.AUTH_USERNAME, BaseRequest.AUTH_PASSWORD);
    Interceptor headerAuthorizationInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            if (!NetworkUtils.isConnected(context)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response from cache ");
                Request request = chain.request();
                CacheControl cacheControl = new 
                   CacheControl.Builder().maxStale(1, 
                   TimeUnit.DAYS).build();

                request = request.newBuilder().cacheControl(cacheControl).build();
                String rawJson = chain.proceed(request).body().string();

                Log.e(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, String.format("req response cache raw JSON response is: %s", rawJson));
                return chain.proceed(request);
            } else {

                Log.e(TAG, "response from network");
                CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder().maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).build();
                prefManager = new PrefManager(context);
                String token = prefManager.getPreference(AppConstant.HEADER_TOKEN);
                Request.Builder request = chain.request().newBuilder();
                request.addHeader(OUTPUT_ACCEPT, APP_JSON);
                request.addHeader(AUTHERIZATION, BEARER + token);
                request.header(CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControl.toString());
                //request.cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE);

                Response response = chain.proceed(request.build());


                return response;
            }
        }
    };
    return headerAuthorizationInterceptor;
}


@Provides
public HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    return httpLoggingInterceptor;
}
```

And i am check cache file in File explorer but showing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Context in your MainActivity, like below:

```
public static Context mContext;
```

In your onCreate(), you can add:

```
mContext = getApplicationContext();
```

Then, in a separate file, example RetrofitCachingInstance:

```
public class RetrofitCachingInstance {

private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = chain -> {

    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    return originalResponse.newBuilder()
            .removeHeader("Pragma")
            .header("Cache-Control",
                    String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "max-age=%d", 60))
            .build();
};

private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String BASE_URL = "YOUR_JSON_URL";

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

    if (retrofit == null) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        client.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
        client.addNetworkInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR);
        client.addInterceptor(provideOfflineCacheInterceptor());
        client.cache(getCache(MainActivity.mContext));

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) 
                // using Gson for deserialization in this case
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

private static Interceptor provideOfflineCacheInterceptor() {

    return chain -> {

        try {
            return chain.proceed(chain.request());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                    .onlyIfCached()
                    .maxStale(2, TimeUnit.DAYS) 
            // accept cached responses up to 2 days old, else hit network request again
                    .build();

            Request offlineCachingRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .removeHeader("Pragma")
                    .cacheControl(cacheControl)
                    .build();

            return chain.proceed(offlineCachingRequest);
        }
    };
}

private static Cache getCache(Context context) {

    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // Cache size is only 10 MB maximum

    return new Cache(MainActivity.mContext.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);

   }
}
```

This should work. Hope this is helpful.